# Cant Perform action on product ,order etc grid

Tags: grid

I have weird issue on magento I was tired alot to reolve it

Issue was: In admin section when I was trying to perform any action in the grid which is showing on right section of catelog,order etc  like this

[image]

When I am trying to perform delete action on any product and click on submit button nothing is happened can anybody suggest whats going on ?
How I can resolve it?
Please help :(
Also in log I found only 1 error

> 2015-08-27T11:21:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 16: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/systema1/public_html/somethingaboutmommy/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

But I think This is not related with this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi anybody face this issue?

Comment: Have you checked for JS errors via the console? Most likely a JS issue.

Comment: I resolved it :), the problem is I did customize few things in validation.js so because of that reasons validation return false so whenever I click on "submit " button of action section nothing was happened. If any one face this kind of issue please check in "js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js" here there is one function called "apply" which is used to create the action of the form.